# How can you view all your grand prix results in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart Wii you could view your results for each grand prix, including how many starts you had. In 8 the only way I see to do this is to go all the way to where you'd select a grand prix and scroll through them. Is there a way to see a list of your grand prix results?